# Webpack file-loader exclude option not working as expected

Tags: webpack, webpack-file-loader

In my webpack config, I want the file-loader plugin to drop all referenced images in the `./dist/images/` folder (including SVGs). At the same time, I would like the file-loader plugin to also drop all referenced font files (for font-awesome) in the  `./dist/assets/webfonts/` folder (this, too, includes SVGs).

The problem I'm having is that standard SVG images are being copied to the `./dist/assets/webfonts/` AND `./dist/images/` folders and font SVGs from font-awesome are being copied to the `./dist/images/` AND `./dist/assets/webfonts/` folders.

But worse than that, all the SVGs in the `./dist/images/` don't contain SVG data, they contain this:

```
module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "./assets/webfonts/logo-text.svg";
```

This is my current module configuration for the file-loader plugin:

```
{ test: /.*\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/, loader: "file-loader", options: { name: "./images/[name]_[hash:7].[ext]" }, exclude:  __dirname +  "/../src/assets/" },
{ test: /.*\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$/, loader: "file-loader", options: { name: "./assets/webfonts/[name].[ext]" }, exclude:  __dirname + "/../src/images/" }
```

You'll notice that for each file-loader entry, I've already excluded the folder it isn't supposed to load files from but that doesn't seem to have worked.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

#### 1. Distinguish between SVG fonts and images

You can use the [outputPath](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#outputpath) option of the file-loader to differentiate between fonts and images like this:

```
{
    test: /.*\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/,
    loader: "file-loader",
    options: {
        name: "[name].[ext]",
        outputPath: (url, resourcePath, context) => {
            const relativePath = path.relative(context, resourcePath);

            // ignore SVG file if its relative path contains "fonts" (in your case "assets")
            if (/\/fonts\//.test(relativePath)) {
                return;
            }

            return `images/${url}`;
        },
    },
},
{
    test: /.*\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$/,
    loader: "file-loader",
    options: {
        name: "[name].[ext]",
        outputPath: (url, resourcePath, context) => {
            const relativePath = path.relative(context, resourcePath);

            // ignore SVG file if its relative path contains "images"
            if (/\/images\//.test(relativePath)) {
                return;
            }

            return `fonts/${url}`;
        },
    },
},
```

...**but** there is still the other issue:

#### 2. Broken SVG content

It seems that only the SVGs of the last section are working. If I first run the fonts and after that the images, only images are built correctly - and vice versa. A workaround would be to add a new section for all SVGs and remove them from the fonts- and images-section.

```
{
    test: /.*\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/,
    loader: "file-loader",
    options: {
        name: "images/[name].[ext]",
    },
},
{
    test: /.*\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
    loader: "file-loader",
    options: {
        name: "fonts/[name].[ext]",
    },
},
{
    test: /\.svg$/,
    loader: "file-loader",
    options: {
        name: "[name].[ext]",
        outputPath: (url, resourcePath, context) => {
            const relativePath = path.relative(context, resourcePath);

            if (/\/images\//.test(relativePath)) {
                // return target for svg images
                return `images/${url}`;
            } else if (/\/fonts\//.test(relativePath)) {
                // return target for svg fonts
                return `fonts/${url}`;
            }

            return `other/${url}`;
        },
    },
},
```